# Methods for calculating (one-parameter subgroup) actions

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions, flows

For $G$ a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra, I am interested in one-parameter subgroup actions on “functions” $f$ of the form
\begin{equation}
   \mathrm{e}^{t L(z)} f(z)
\end{equation}
where for explanatory reasons $t$ is real and $L(z)$ is a representation of a generator of $\mathfrak{g}$ acting on $f(z)$. I am leaving the term “function” vague because what I am ultimately am interested in may be even distributional.

An example. Let $G= \operatorname{SU}(1,1)$, where a representation in terms of first-order differential operators for its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ is given by $L_0 = z \partial_z + k$, $L_1 = \partial_z$, $l_{-1} = z^2 \partial_z +2kz$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$, the open complex unit disc. We consequently consider $f(z) \in L^2(\mathbb{D})$; $k$ is dependent on the type of representation, but for this example just real.

For the case of $L_0$ and $L_1$ we can interestingly consider this as an instantiation of Lie's advective flow for Abelian groups and rewrite it as the [shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) in suitable canonical coordinates, the [Abel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation). This straightforwardly gives for example
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{t z \partial_z} f(z) = f(\mathrm{e}^t z)\,.
\end{equation}
The literature discusses this under the theory of [iterated functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function), too.

An immediate problem seem to be generators $L(z)$ that have an inhomogeneous part such that the canonical coordinates cannot make it “advective” ($z \partial_z f(z) = 0$ is the one-dimensional steady advective equation). Such a “non-advective” generator is the mentioned generator $L_{-1}$. The straight-forward way of trying to split the inhomogeneous part off by using the [BCH-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) does not make things easier in the case where for $\mathrm{e}^{X+Y}$ one has not both $[X,[X,Y]] = 0$ and $[Y,[Y,X]] = 0$. Note that in this examplary case of $G= \text{SU}(1,1)$ one can just calculate the action by brute force, but I am looking for a more elegant solution that is also applicable in more complicated cases.

My question is this: **has Lie's advective flow “method” that I've outlined been generalized? Are there other effective methods to compute such actions?**

I am ultimately interested in more general Lie algebras and general group orbits that are not necessarily only parametrized by one Lie algebra generator like above. **I would also be very grateful for resources for methods to solve such a more general case, even if not connected to what I have discussed above.**

Comment: I would have tried to work out the flows of the vector fields first, and then get the functions to transform correspondingly by composition with the flows. But I don't remember anything about advective flows.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I edited both instances